# What is the best experience for exporting a spreadsheet on a mobile device?

Tags: usability, mobile, data, download

I'm currently tasked with creating an Export feature for a logged in experience.

Users have access to a list of people, that can reach an upper limit of ~120 individuals. And our users want to be able to customize a spreadsheet of customizable info (Name, DOB, Gender, Emergency Contact, etc.) to fit their needs. There are currently ~30 different fields, with the potential of adding more.

Since our platform is responsive, many users could potentially export their group while on their mobile phone.

**What is the best experience for that mobile flow? Is it simply an email that gets generated with an attached spreadsheet? Should it open up in a new tab? Should we not even provide this option while on mobile, because it may not be contextually relevant?**

Comment: I think the last question is the most important, and needs to be answered first - how can you choose the how, when you haven't even decided whether it's a requirement or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly I don't feel like users will want to export on their phone and if they do it'll be an edge case scenario. I would say that if they do tap export on mobile, then it should open in the browser unless you plan to allow them to edit it on the device then it should open in the devices default spreadsheet software

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. That's my inclination as well - Although I'm not sure how native mobile browsers handle spreadsheets. I know that for PDFs, they get opened in a new tab, and users have to pinch/zoom. Spreadsheets, though...

Comment: Yeah its not gona be optimal to open it on any mobile device, due to the screen size and amount of content. The user ca always turn the device landscape to allow them more room. Spreadsheets don't really work to well on mobile but the option is still there, google sheets has a mobile version of the app. To be honest this is an edge case scenario, i'd concentrate on the website version as thats the main area of traffic and just try and make the mobile version as user friendly as possible.